# MYSQL|Datatype for states

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes, states

I need to figure out which datatype to use for **states**.

Should it be `SET` or `VARCHAR` or anything else?

```
CREATE TABLE actors(
    state SET('USA','Germany','....)
    )
```

alternatively

```
CREATE TABLE actors(
state VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's going to be tens or over hundred of the countries, it's best to use separate table.

```
CREATE TABLE states(
  state_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

*It's also recommended to use foreign key on the state_id so if you want to delete a state from your database, it wouldn't break other data depending on it.*

If each actor is going to be assigned only to one state (1:1), you can use column in the actors table.

```
CREATE TABLE actors(
   actor_id INT ...,
   state_id INT,
)
```

Or if each actor can be assigned to more states (1:N), use another table for these relations:

```
CREATE TABLE actors(
   actor_id INT ...,
)
CREATE TABLE actors_to_states(
   actor_id INT,
   state_id INT
)
```

Answer (score 2):

SET is a compound datatype containing values from predefined set of possible values. If table contains such a data then according to relational databases theory it is not in 1NF. So it is only few special cases where this approach is reasonable. In most cases I suggest using separate table for countries like in example below:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (id SMALLINT, name VARCHAR(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer these type of questions , you should so little bit of data analysis and ask some questions to your data like :

> 1. What is the maximum size of my data ?

In your case it will be the country which has the largest name .Note this down. Add 20 to remain on safe side .

> 2. Will my data always contain numbers or characters, or combination ?

In your case only characters . So it is `varchar` .

Also plan your data-model such that you don't need to edit afterwards .Use of `set` would not be recommended by me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the standard abbreviations (US for USA, DE for Germany) and put it in

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL
```

That way, it is compact (2 bytes) and readable by users.  Then, if you want, you can have another table that spells out the country names.

If an `actor` can belong to multiple `states`, then this won't work, and you do need to have a `SET`.  If you need that, we can discuss it further.